# Список с мультивыбором

Tags: excel, макросы

Подскажите как можно сделать в одной ячейке - мультивыбор (несколько вариантов одновременно) из списка, так чтобы во второй ячейке для соответствующих этим вариантов значений из второго списка происходило сложение?

Т.е есть:
Вар1-10.
Вар2-20.
Вар3-40.

В ячейке я должен выбрать Вар1,Вар3 и в другой получить 50

Про мультивыбор гугл сразу выдаёт пример макроса, но как его доработать не знаю

Comment: В ячейке можно, если выбирать поочередно (выбрали один вариант - в другой ячейке значение, выбрали второй раз - сумма значений). Но можно при выделении ячейки вызвать `UserForm`` со списком. Макрос пишется в Вашем файле-примере +)

Comment: Хотелось бы поподробней о проблеме. А так могу порекомендовать воспользоваться "Расширенным фильтром".

Comment: [вот здесь](https://www.planetaexcel.ru/techniques/1/181/) 3й вариант ( С накоплением в той же ячейке) - это  практически то, что нужно, только не хватает части со сложением.
Т.е., мне нужно, чтобы в столбце В были бы ещё числа (напротив Саша, Маша.. в примере), и при мультивыборе в С, в соответствующих ячейках D они бы уже складывались.

@TilekSamiev

Answer (score 0):

Вот код макроса мультивыбора. Только он суммирует в ту же ячейку, а не в отдельную.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C5")) Is Nothing And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    newVal = Target
    Application.Undo
    oldval = Target
    If Len(oldval) <> 0 And oldval <> newVal Then
        Target = Target + newVal
    Else
        Target = newVal
    End If
    If Len(newVal) = 0 Then Target.ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Вы содрали макрос, заменив только объединение суммированием. Это код Николая Павлова. Этот макрос есть в статье по ссылке, которую показал @Denis Ka в своем комментарии к вопросу

Comment: не отрицаю этого. Но все же я додумался до ответа за 5 минут, чем задавать такой вопрос сюда

Comment: Ответ неправильный. Объединять нужно текстовые значения, а суммировать соответствующие им числове данные. А о том, что макрос мултивыбора был найден сразу,. автор еще в описани вопроса упоминал

Answer (score 0):

Решение по объединению данных уже есть, Вы сами его нашли по ссылке.

Для суммирования впишите формулу

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(ЕЧИСЛО(ПОИСК($A$2:$A$10;C2))*$B$2:$B$10)
```